# Tableau + Azure Data Lake Gen2 multiple files or folder

Tags: azure, tableau-desktop, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am able to see my containers in an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 endpoint with signing in the AD.

I am able to see the files and select 1 singular file while browsing but the question is - is there an ability to select the folder of the container and bring in every single file from that container to build my dataset if they are all the same.

Or do I require something like an external table in Azure Data Explorer of some some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag the first file from your collection into the data pane

[image]

[image: then do union]

[image: like this]

then right-click and use the edit union option
[image: Use the Wildcard option]